# Connection to Asterisk from php

Tags: php, linux, asterisk

how to connect to Asterisk server or how to execute asterisk commands?
i have been trying `exec`,`shell_exec` and e.t.c not working but if i try `exec('ls')` it works great.i have installed chan_dongle so i need to use `"asterisk -rx 'dongle sms dongle0 $phonenumber $textmessage'"`, but it not working,from console it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private function my_exec($cmd, $input = '')
{
    $proc = proc_open($cmd, array(0 => array('pipe', 'r'), 1 => array('pipe', 'w'), 2 => array('pipe', 'w')), $pipes);
    fwrite($pipes[0], $input);
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    $rtn = proc_close($proc);
    return array('stdout' => $stdout,
        'stderr' => $stderr,
        'return' => $rtn
    );
}
```

Check this function, it helped me once.